# PHP: are URL variables in the namespace they were declared?

Tags: php, namespaces, urlvariables

I read that any variable declared after a namespace is then part of that namespace.  I was confused then when reading about "URL variables":

```
<?php 
namespace OddTeaFlavors
return "
<nav>
<a href='index.php?flavor=acidRain'> Try Our new Acid Rain Flavor! </a>
</nav>
";
```

Would the URL variable `flavor` be part of the `OddTeaFlavors` namespace?

Comment: flavor cannot be a variable. it is part of a link.

Comment: @user2411276 Its perfectly fine to have dynamically generated keys with GET requests.

Comment: Beginner-level question, for sure, but this is valid... upvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no variable in that namespace, a string (which is data) is being returned. Once the data is out, you're no longer inside of that namespace. Once your HTML response gets sent, you're no longer even on the server.

Comment: Thanks, I was thrown off by the term "URL variable", and wondered if a secret variable had been created behind the scenes.

Comment: Nope, it's variable in the context of the _browser_, but not when presented to PHP in the middle of a string